# Apache serves different HTTPS vhost on server, instead of requested vhost

Tags: apache, amazon-linux

site1.com does not have https enabled and no SSL cert installed.
site2.com does have https enabled.
When a site visitor requests https://site1.com, they receive a SSL certificate mismatch error and if they click 'proceed anyway', they are sent to https://site2.com

What can I do to either host, to redirect the traffic back to site1.com, while removing the https, since site1.com does not have an SSL cert?

I tried this in the .htaccess file of site2.com

```
RewriteEngine on
#if the request is actually for site1 forward them to site1
RewriteRule "^site1.com" "http://site1.com" [R]
#if the request is actually for site1 (with www prefix) forward them to site 1
RewriteRule "^www.site1.com" "http://site1.com" [R]
```

Comment: Get a SSL cert for site1.com.  With letsencrypt offering free certs there no reason not to.  Plenty of reasons TO do it as well - https://www.wired.com/story/google-chrome-https-not-secure-label/

Comment: The unexpected behavior is that Apache is sending the visitor to site2.com when they have not requested that site.  I want to stop that behavior.  How do I configure apache to not server the wrong site?

Comment: The issue is that is the only site configured to accept connections on port 443.  Any/every name pointing to port 443 on your IP will get site2.com ...

Comment: That is correct and is the core of my question.  Does Apache have a mechanism to remediate that behavior?  I would expect that the origin of the request (being site1.com) ought to be apparent to the end result (serving the content of site2.com) so that you could then redirect or modify the behavior of the request fulfillment.